# Rails Error - Uninitialized Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Upon setting up a new rails project I have come across the following issues on the `rails s` command

```
john-MacBook-Pro:coffee john$ rails s
/Users/john/Development/coffee/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Coffee>': uninitialized constant Coffee::Rails::Application (NameError)
    from /Users/john/Development/coffee/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What exactly is causing this and how do I fix it?

Thanks for looking.

Application.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Coffee
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post your application.rb file?

Comment: hope you are running this command inside the folder holding the code :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to have called your application 'coffee'. This means that you have a `module Coffee` declaration in your `config/application.rb` file.

Rails uses the [coffee-rails](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails) gem to support coffee script in a rails application and this also declares a `module Coffee`.

You have inadvertently created a name clash with your choice of application name.